# h2o wave app with realtime dashboard (using ui.small_series_stat_card)

Tags: python, user-interface, charts, dashboard, h2o-wave

I would like to create h2o_wave interactive app (not a script) with several pages/screens (using tabs), one of which would display a dashboard with continuously updated charts in real time. Something like this https://wave.h2o.ai/docs/examples/dashboard, but as an interactive app (https://wave.h2o.ai/docs/apps). The goal is to create a GUI for data logger device.

Creating a dashboard as a script, for example following this tutorial https://wave.h2o.ai/docs/tutorial-monitor, is easy, but when i try to replicate it as an app (following this example https://wave.h2o.ai/docs/examples/tab-delete), the code execution gets stuck on a while loop that redraws the charts and anything beyond won't get executed - in the navigation bar example it gets stuck in await display_tab(q) where i put the chart redraw while True loop.

So how should one combine these two concepts in a single app?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please provide a minimal, reproducible example with code from your app. I can probably help.

Answer (score 0):

H2O Wave lead maintainer here.

> the code execution gets stuck on a while loop that redraws the charts and anything beyond won't get executed

Python programs run in a single thread. By telling your code to run the same code over and over (infinite loop), you basically kill the thread. What you want instead is to run your updates in a background job (task/process) and keep the main thread free to run further, listen for user events, etc.

See this [blog post](https://medium.com/@unusualcode/background-jobs-in-wave-or-how-not-to-kill-your-ui-ae1fed95693a) to learn how to deal with background tasks in (not only) Wave.